# css ul li 100% utilization of space inside fixed div but dynamic li

Tags: html, css

I have one page in which the width of the `div` is fixed and it's centralized.

and `ul>li` are also needed to be centralized by taking their own `100% width` even spaces on left and right.

in this situtation, li are dynamic and they can deleted/edited/added.

so I don't know how should I proceed further.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">    
     <head>        
         <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>          
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
         <title>Untitled</title>
         <style>
         .first {text-align:center;width:980px}
         .first ul { float:left;width:100%;text-align:center;float:left; }
         .first ul li { list-style-type:none;float:left; display:inline-block }
         </style>
     </head>  
     <body style="margin:0 auto">  
         <div id="first">     
               <ul>       
                   <li>first li</li>      
                   <li>second li</li>      
                   <li>third li</li>      
                   <li>4th li</li>       
                   <li>5th li</li>     
              </ul>  
         </div>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: sorry, css code is added to the description

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understoon your question but I think what you might be after is in [this example I made for you](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/4NRx2/).

---

After your comment, I updated, is [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/4NRx2/5/) more what you're after?

Comment: Updated. Please see new link.

Comment: li elements lined up evenly spaced filling up the whole line. and #first is having fixed width of 980px

Comment: I don't think this is possible, unless you go for a table. If this is tabular data and not a menu, that's a fine solution.

Comment: oh ok. i'll try some more time. and if i don't get the solution then i have to do something else .  thanks Kyle for prompt replies

Answer (score 0):

```
#first{
    width:100%
}
#first ul {
    width:100%;
}
#first ul li  {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
}
```

You are messing up selectors:
`id="first"` is referenced like `#first`

---

My advice is to user a table for such evenly spaced menu: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/GvXzf/

```
<table style="width: 100%"><tr>
    <td>first li</td>      
    <td>second li</td>      
    <td>third li</td>      
    <td>4th li</td>       
    <td>5th li</td> 
</tr></table>
```

Or you can write a javascript too, that makes the menu items evenly spaced, if you want to stick with ul and lis.

Comment: Can you describe more fully what you mean by "not taking 100% of their own?"

Comment: you want the li elements lined up evenly spaced filling up the whole line?

Comment: yes, right. that's what i want. but they are dynamic, if something is removed or added. it should adjust automatically

Comment: @dave tested it on jsfiddle, check the link in the answer